# In Blender 3.5, how to make a braid?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry-nodes, hair, procedural

It is hard to precisely control the location of the virtual Hair Tie by changing the values on the Braid Hair Curves. The [official Blender online document](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/hair/guides/braid_hair_curves.html) lacks of the detail about this issue:

[image]

One developer said that

> it is to be expected that the origin of Hair Tie (i.e. the torus) would be considered in the position of the "virtual".

However, no matter how I change the origin of the torus, the hair still does not go through the ring. Moreover, the braid is not symmetric with respect to the Y axis. It is always tilted to one side.
[image]

[image]

In Blender 3.5, how to make a braid?

Additional tip: It looks like using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> to apply all transformation on the emitting mesh and torus helps little bit, but still hair position is not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

No one answers this question? Okay, here is my **incomplete** solution to make a braid in v3.5.

**Step 1:**
[image]
Note: if the torus is transformed with a different origin, you probably have a trouble to properly align the torus with the hair tie in the future.

**Step 2:** Create the emitting mash (the scalp)
[image]

**Step 3:** Create the Fur, and then five geometry modifiers are automatically attached to the Fur.
[image]

**Step 4:** Although the Generate Hair modifier can help me change the hair length and hair material, one of the mistakes I made during my creation of the braid is to add a Generate Hair modifier in the stack. I don't know how to use this modifier properly, so it is better not to use it until modeling your braid is finished.
[image]

**Step 5:** Add a Braid Hair Curves modifier. Turning on the Existing Guide Map is important, because the location of the hair tie will be determined by this map. And since the map is turned on, the Guide Distance and Guide Mask on the modifier are no longer active (i.e. no longer affects the final result). The next step would be to build this map.
[image]

**Step 6:** The Guide Map consists of hair guides. And in order to see these guides, you can turn off the Interpolate Hair modifier. And then use the Slide brush in the Sculpt mode to align one of the hair ties with respect to the Y axis, so that the hair braid will be symmetrical with respect to the Y axis.
[image]

Step 7: To make just one braid, now delete any additional hair guide on the map. This will delete any additional hair tie.
[image]

**The final result:**
[image]
The final result is still problematic! The geometry modifiers just ignore the existence of the collision detector.

Although I do not know how to solve this problem, some potential keys to tackle this problem is to build more geometry nodes within the Braid Hair Curves modifier. For example, use simulation nodes to detect the collision, and one candidate would be [Raycast node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/geometry/raycast.html), and there is a friendly [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lHbhC9SOSw8) talking about how to use it. Another useful candidate would be [Shortest Edge Path node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/shortest_edge_paths.html).

However, I am a beginner in creating my own geometry node tree. Therefore, if anyone can build a node tree to detect the hair collision and thus correct the paths of the hair curves, then I will definitely award all the bounty from this question to you. Highly appreciated.

A sample file of the braid is attached:
[image]

Comment: the collision detection is only for brushes not GN.  you can get collision detection without simulations if you're okay with only one collision step (with is plenty); raycast is the answer.

Comment: I think that the collision detection is only 40% of the question, and the other 60% is which path the hair curves would go after the collision is detected.  Do you know where I can find the source code of the "Deflect Emitter" for the Blender hair particle system please? Because that source code may give a clue on how the hair curves go after the collision.

Comment: Have you tried the *Shrinkwrap Hair Curves* modifier/asset that comes with Blender 3.5? It can fix the "hair goes through the head" problem. But it also messes up the position of the torus. Not sure if that helps.

Comment: I guess that shrinkwrapping hair may force the hair to stick on the surface of the scalp. This would create a problem for fluffy hair. I have not tried it, and so this is just my guess. However, my plan to use geo nodes in Blender to create hair is abandoned, after knowing [physics-based grooming] [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4KsL2meivhQ ] is on the horizon. What time to be alive!